# How to use echarts graph force update single node ? Not reload whole echarts

Tags: echarts

I use echarts graph force, and it can support update single node, when i click node and save change, echarts always reload, then i can't find changes immediately. So, Is there any good solution ?

expect: After data change, echarts can be local refresh single node, don't change Original layout

Comment: Could you, please, add some short sample what you already have / tried, so we can help you to improve your solution?